# Image resizer "creating breakpoints"

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

I'm using *ASP.NET ImageResizer library*, I have my application working well.

But I came across two problems, first is single ip requesting many images like:

```
image.jpeg?width=10 
image.jpeg?width=11 
image.jpeg?width=12 
image.jpeg?width=13
```

But this I simply resolve alowing X request per minute.

My second problem is that I dont want to create ALL images, I want breakpoints, somethig like:

- 1º - 320w- 213h
- 2º - 453w-   302h
- 3º - 579w-   386h
- 4º - 687w-   458h
- 5º - 786w-   524h

...
 This table I get from this [great article](http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-images-101-part-9-image-breakpoints/).

My question is can I do it with ImageResizer library configurations, or do I have to work around to overtake this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageResizer offers ["Presets"](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/presets), and you can lock it down so only presets can be used. These are typically used to create breakpoints as you describe.

If you have attackers, there are many IPS systems that can detect malicious attacks based on pattern and block them. CloudFlare is also good at this.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for answer, I do not think I was very clear on the question I asked. I will create another more clear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479931/imageresizer-return-closest-image-breakpoint