# ImageResizer return closest image breakpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

Like @Nathanael Jones answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35460860/5842138) *ImageResizer library* have "Presets" to create some kind of breakpoints.

I want have breakpoints as I mentioned on my other question:

1º - 320w- 213h

2º - 453w- 302h

3º - 579w- 386h

and so on..

My question is can I request an image like `"?w=300&h=200"`, and return my closest breakpoint, in this case was first one.

Comment: Yes you can, but you'll need to code it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in to pick presets for you, or "snap" to the closest one. That said, it's easy to implement using the `Config.Current.Pipleine.Rewrite` event, where you can access `e.QueryString["width"]` and `e.QueryString["height"]`, and change those values as well.